# ASP RadioButtonList auto change item after click

Tags: c#, asp.net

I bind my RadioButtonList but when i select item and use button after click RadiobuttonList change checked item to first row form bind

This happen too when i use autopostback='true" and RadioButtonList as select-sender

```
if (!IsPostBack)
{
    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"server=localhost; database=PS_User; trusted_connection=true;"))
    {
        con.Open();

        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(@"Select * from S1 WHERE PART =@1 AND PART IS NOT NULL Order by point", con);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@0", 0);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@1", 1);

        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        da.Fill(ds);

        RadioButtonList1.DataTextField = "Name";
        RadioButtonList1.DataValueField = "Point";
        RadioButtonList1.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
        RadioButtonList1.DataBind();
    }
}

protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (RadioButtonList1.SelectedIndex > -1)
    {
        Label1.Text = "You chose: " +
            RadioButtonList1.SelectedItem.Text;
    }
}
```

[Bug](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zdPQk.png)

Comment: I've tested both the button click and the `OnSelectedIndexChanged` with autopostback set to true. It works as expected both times. Are you using `UpdatePanel` or something like that? Because the problem is not in the above snippet.

Answer (score 0):

Yes i used
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=K2DL8jHEzgE&feature=youtu.be

```
    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
        <ContentTemplate>
            <asp:RadioButtonList ID="RadioButtonList1" runat="server" AutoPostBack="False" OnSelectedIndexChanged="RadioButtonList1_SelectedIndexChanged">
            </asp:RadioButtonList>
            <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" OnClick="Button1_Click" Text="Button" ClientIDMode="Static" />
            <br />
            <br />
            <br />
            <br />
            <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>
            <br />
        </ContentTemplate>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Answer (score 0):

Im fix thix problem

```
    RadioButtonList1.DataValueField = "Point";
```

Should be

```
    RadioButtonList1.DataValueField = "Name";
```

I have anoter problem and i cant create new topic so i ask here:
 Is posible usnig declare inside string query in ASP wtihout SQL injection?
I make a query and work fine but i must add declare inside query

```
string queryString = @"Declare @Slot Tinyint,@empty smallint
```

Becouse when i try this Doest not work any more:

```
 cmd2.Parameters.Add("@Slot", SqlDbType.TinyInt); cmd2.Parameters.Add("@empty", SqlDbType.SmallInt);
```